# Hadoop in AWS EMR: Will closing terminal kill hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, ssh

Is it safe to close my terminal or turn off my computer without killing my Hadoop job?

I am in the middle of a Hadoop job running via a cluster on Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce. I have my terminal open, where I am ssh'd into my master node. When I try to close my terminal, I get a warning that all processes will be killed. Will this kill my Hadoop job as well? Or can I power off my computer and ssh again later? Do I need a special tool (like tmux) to do this?

If it matters, I am using the default (`bin/bash`) terminal in Ubuntu 13.10. I started the job with a Pig script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can happily kill the terminal . The mapreduce job is running on the EMR cluster and will continue to do so. You could come back , log into the master node and check `lynx http://localhost:9100` for jotracker status anytime.
 To kill a hadoop job you have to run the command `hadoop job -kill jobflowid` . 
So, moot point is - at any time you can log into the jobtracker and see the status of your job.Also note that jobtracker's port address 9100 is default on EMR cluster. 
 Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

Closing terminal will not kill the already fired job u can also view the job status from the jobtracker public url public-dns-of-cluster:9100/jobtacker.jsp.